# How Can I add class using jquery form other file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, js.class

Hi I have this javascript(jquery) for adding classes to my `<html>` and `<body>` tags in my view

```
  <script>
 $("html").addClass("new1");
 $("body").addClass("new2");
 </script>
```

So I want to change from view to specific js file like main.js, I create this file and copy paste my code, and I call in my view like this:

```
   <script src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>
```

Why doesn't it work? Can anyone help me?

Comment: 1) what is ~ ? 2) Script needs to load after window load

Comment: 1)~ is te tag used for render location in .net, I'm not loading now?, I'm new  in JS

Comment: If the `~` is in the code client-side then the browser won't know what to do with that.  Make sure ASP.NET is translating it to a proper path server-side before delivering the page to the client.

Comment: Also know about the browser console: ctrl-shift-j or F12

Comment: try `<script> $(function(){$("html").addClass("new1");$("body").addClass("new2");})</script>`

Comment: It works, but I have want to use this js file for all my project, how can I separate this part of code form other js code?, for example, If I add another View and I call this js for another function, It change my html and body too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This path doesn't mean anything to the browser:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>
```

Unless the current folder *literally* has a sub-folder called `~`, then that won't find anything.  It needs to be the actual path to the file.  For example:

```
<script src="/Scripts/main.js"></script>
```

or:

```
<script src="../Scripts/main.js"></script>
```

or whatever the path to that JavaScript file is from the currently loaded URL.

The JavaScript code itself doesn't do anything differently whether the `script` tag contains the code as content or references it from another source.  It behaves the same either way.

---

Based on the comments below, if you're just asking how to create a function in JavaScript then that's simple.  Something like this:

```
function addClasses() {
    $("html").addClass("new1");
    $("body").addClass("new2");
}
```

Then you can call that function any time you like:

```
addClasses();
```

Comment: It works, but I have want to use this js file for all my project, how can I separate this part of code form other js code?, for example, If I add another View and I call this js for another function, It change my html and body too

Comment: I have $(function () {
    $("html").addClass("new1");
    $("body").addClass("new2");
})

Comment: @Demain: You can reference this JavaScript file from any page.  The code will execute the same way on any page.

Comment: Yes I know it, but I want to add more code for other views in same file and I don't want to call these first functions on my other views

Comment: @Demain: It's not clear what you mean.  You can organize your code however you want, and invoke it whenever you want.  Have you tried something that isn't working as expected?

Comment: I want to know how can I separate one function for other, for
the time to call my main.js not run all scripts in my main.js

Comment: @Demain: So... You're asking how to create a function in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, for this $("html").addClass("hundred");
    $("body").addClass("loginbg"); and how to call in view in my html and body tag

Comment: @Demain: I've updated the answer with an example of creating a function.

Comment: And how can I call in my view? I try <html class="addClases"> but It not work

Comment: @Demain: You'd call it from JavaScript code, just as I demonstrated at the end of the answer.  In any JavaScript code block, invoke the function: `addClasses();`  You can't just write the function name anywhere in the HTML and expect the browser to know what you mean.